# How do I make Windows recognize commands from earphones buttons/controls?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, sound-card, headphones

I'm running Window 10 1909, up to date with Windows Update, on a fairly new laptop (from last year, it's an Acer A515-51G-72DB) and I'm trying to get my Samsung earphone's buttons to control media playback. I checked and my plug has 4 channels and I can successfully use it on this laptop for both audio and microphone.

I haven't tried setting this up before, but this is a fresh Windows install, so perhaps I need a specific driver that Windows Update won't provide? I'm pretty sure I don't have faulty hardware or anything like that...

Comment: Well since such earphones usually don’t have special drivers but if you had wired headphones of a company that specializes in selling such products have drivers that would work with the in-line controls to work with the media playback.

Comment: So it's not done in a standardized way? Then how does Android work with lots of different earphones?

Comment: You are talking android, the base is the same and the input signals from the in-line controls are the same as well, except if you use the iPhone specific wired EarPods. So it is generalized, but in windows, there are two things that matter, 1. Support of the same audio jack capable of inputs and 2. Only a few wired headphones support in-line controls. Also *as far as I know*, the chances of you being able to use the in-line controls seem to be very low

Comment: @FabioFreitas - Windows isn't Android.  Android handles devices in an entirely different way.  You cannot compare Android to Windows with regards to devices like a headset.

Comment: @ Valay_17 I'm sorry, but I could understand very little of what you wrote. There's always a chance that my english is tricking me, but could you clarify/rephrase? Also, as I stated before, I'm using earphones from Samsung that _do_ have buttons to control media playback/volume on Android.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I understand that, but perhaps I should have made my point on how information from an audio input is simple (i.e. 4 channels and that's it), so perhaps it wouldn't be that hard "decoding" it, given the proper drivers.

Comment: @FabioFreitas Sure, I’ll make it simple. In Android phones, there is a dataset for the input from the in-line controls to be recognized no matter what company those earphones are of, provided they are meant to be supported for Androids(if you would use Apple’s EarPods, their in-line controls won’t work for Androids). Windows doesn’t have a dataset to recognize these input codes. Only a few headphones(eg.Sennheiser) with in-line controls have drivers for Windows in order to support them. Now you may argue that Bluetooth headphones with audio playback controls can be used on both of them........

Comment: ....With ease, but if you connect Bluetooth headphones to Windows, they always install the appropriate drivers. So, if you wish to use the earphones’ in-line controls on windows, search for it on GitHub, where someone must have written a code which would bring the dataset of Android to Windows and then use it or wait for this question to grab the attention of the big programming players in the room to help you out or maybe even the Google-fu masters in the room to find a way out. Hope you understood it this time.

Comment: @Valay_17 ah, now I get it! I'm going to take a look on GitHub, thanks!

Comment: @FabioFreitas Good luck finding, let us know if you were lucky finding it.